# Program's windows suddenly don't display and appear black in taskbar thumbnail previews

Tags: windows-10

Suddenly, something happened (when I ran some computations, but the memory never reached 100%) that windows of already running applications appear black in the taskbar thumbnail previews and cannot be displayed when invoked (through either Alt-Tab as well as clicking their thumbnail preview in the Taskbar). Short illustration:

[image]

The only "R" program displayed correctly in the thumbnail is the one on the very right - but that one I ran after this problem appeared. If I run new programs now, they don't have any of these problems. But the programs already running before I cannot invoke and display correctly. Not only "R" have this problem, but also other apps.

Is this fixable without killing the programs? I worry a bit I might have some unsaved data there, so I'd better avoid that if possible.

Comment: Are those still doing something, consuming CPU?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen no no. But some of them were, when it happened, I got scared that the system got overloaded, so I killed them; then I checked the Task manager for whether the memory was exhausted, but it wasn't. The CPU went close to zero but the windows haven't recovered. Not only "R", but also other apps that started prior to this event have this problem.